# OnEditorActionListener code

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I'm trying to get this code working. It has been posted as a solution to detecting the "done" or "next" button on a softkeyboard but I get the error "must implement inherited abstract method..onEditorAction.."

```
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

textEdit5.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int keycode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(arg1 == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION){
             btnSave.requestFocus();
            return true;
    }

    return false;

    });
```

Comment: You should override the method. See my answer. Tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `@Override` the method for proper execution.

```
textEdit5.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(arg1 == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION){
            btnSave.requestFocus();
            return true;
 }
return false;

});
```

This should work.