# Getting compile error trying to set SetOnEditorActionListener

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an "Enter" softkey handler for an EditText and was getting basically the same problem as described here . . . 
[OnEditorActionListener code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932899/oneditoractionlistener-code)

i.e., "must implement inherited abstract method..onEditorAction.." so I tried using the solution listed in that link, but in an even more simplified form just to try to get it to compile . . .

```
edVacLevel.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
   @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int keycode) {
    return true;
     }
  });
```

... and now it flags OnEditorActionListener and says *"Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method "*
Yet looking at other examples on the web and in StackOverflow, this seems to be the canonical way to handle Enter Keys in an EditText.   So what am I doing wrong?  (Android Studio 2.2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your paraments for onEditorAction() method. They should be.
So your code should look like

```
@Override
 public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
     if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
         //Do your stuff here
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Java is complaining because you are supposed to override the exact method name with respective parameter types.